# Find the marginal PMF of X given the following joint PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Oh boy, so this is a tough one.

Let X and Y be 2 random variables with the joint pmf:

$$p(x,y) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}p^{y}(1-p)^{x-y}}{y!(x-y)!}$$

$$y=0,1,\ldots,x  $$  $$x = 0,1,2,\ldots$$

Find the marginal pmf of X and what is the name of the obtained distribution?

I'm having a really hard time with this, first of all,  am I supposed to multiply p(x,y) with x to obtain the marginal distribution of X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_{y=0}^x \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x}p^{y}(1-p)^{x-y}}{y!(x-y)!} \\[10pt]
= {}& \underbrace{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x \cdot\frac 1 {x!}}_{\text{``constant"}}\  \sum_{y=0}^x \frac{x!}{y!(x-y)!} p^y(1-p)^{x-y} \\[10pt]
= {} & e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x \cdot\frac 1 {x!} \underbrace{\Big(p + (1-p)\Big)^x}_{\text{binomial theorem}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^x}{x!}.\quad\longleftarrow\text{This should look familiar.}
\end{align}

Notice that the word "constant" in this case means not depending on $y$.  It is the fact that that quantity does not change as $y$ goes from $0$ to $x$ that justifies pulling it out from under the "$\sum$".

Comment: how did you pull out $\frac{1}{x!}$ outside the sum? it looks like you put in $\frac{x!}{x!}$ in the equation and took out the denominator.

Comment: @user125535 : Correct.  That can be pulled out because it doesn't change as $y$ goes from $0$ to $x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: BTW, the marginal distribution of the other variable is also a Poisson distribution, with a smaller expected value. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: could you explain the thought process behind adding $\frac{x!}{x!}$ in the second step of the equation? did you just instantly see it as a poisson distribution and that would be the best step?..

Comment: It came from the fact that $\dfrac{\bullet}{y!(x-y)!}$ looks like a binomial coefficient except for the numerator, and $\Big(\text{something}^y\cdot\text{something}^{x-y}\Big)$ also fits in with the binomial theorem. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks :) if you found the marginal distribution for Y, would you mind sharing it so I know what you mean by a poisson distribution with smaller expected value? if not, that's fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wouldn't use the same symbol, lower-case $y$, to refer to two different things: the random variable and the argument to the probability mass function. I would call the random variable capital $Y$ and the argument lower-case $y$.  That way one can understand things like $\Pr(Y=y)=\text{something}$ and $\Pr(Y\le y) =\text{something}$.  At any rate, $X$ has a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda$, $Y$ has a Poisson distribution with expected value $p\lambda$, $X-Y$ has a Poisson distribution with expected value $(1-p)\lambda$, and $Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The marginal pmf of $X$ is $$p_X(x) = \sum_y p(x,y)$$
the sum being over all values of $y$ for which $p(x,y) \ne 0$.
In this case the Binomial Theorem may be helpful.